# Interpreting Jenks Natural breaks results

Tags: clustering, python

I do not come from a strong math background at all, so even basic concepts confuse me, if this sounds too "basic" sorry.

I was going through a book in bioinformatics about finding positions (nucleotide) within a genome.

I found some positions which I placed in an array and wanted to find any natural "clusters" that appeared to predict the presence of certain structures/features within the genome.

Enough googling lead me to wanting to use "Jenks Natural Breaks" algorithm, which I did, since my data is one dimensional.

I found an implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416408/scikit-learn-how-to-run-kmeans-on-a-one-dimensional-array) and got the resulting graph from my array:

```
x = [316, 697, 797, 3355, 36146, 240727, 329885, 338998, 412388, 480358, 
539407, 562037, 745340, 917334, 1000512, 1024954, 1030754, 1038839]
```

[image: jenks result]

My book tells me I am to expect a cluster around the positions `316, 697, 797` , does this graph support that claim strongly? I assume since there is the first breaks on the very bottom it does, but I would like someone to explain it to a layman if possible. Thanks.

Comment: what is position 316 on the graph.  Is it where teh y-axis is nearly zero?

Comment: @EngrStudent     Do you mean the second dotted horizontal line for position 316? That is just where the program made another break.